# Why is my Discord Bot in GitHub not working?

Tags: python, discord, yaml

When I run `main.py` it's giving me this error. I was just trying to replicate a bot from GitHub and I didn't know it would be this difficult, here is the GitHub:

https://github.com/Normynator/RagnaDBot

````
C:\testebot\RagnaDBot>python main.py
INFO:Config logging is enabled and set to: 10
DEBUG:Using proactor: IocpProactor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\testebot\RagnaDBot\main.py", line 29, in <module>
    _settings = load.load_settings(_config)
  File "C:\testebot\RagnaDBot\lib\load.py", line 11, in load_settings
    document = yaml.load(document)
TypeError: load() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Loader'```
````

`load.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import yaml
import logging
from lib import mvp  # required for yaml
from lib.mvp import MVP


def load_settings(path):
    with open(path) as f:
        document = f.read()
        document = yaml.load(document)   - i think the problem is possibly here
        logging.debug(document)
    return document
```

`main.py`:

```
# Path to the config file
_config = "config.yml"
_client = discord.Client()
_settings = load.load_settings(_config) -    problem possibly be here too
_mvp_list = load.parse_mvp_list(_settings['mvp_list'])
_channel = discord.Object(id=_settings['channel_id'])
_debug_core = False
_time_mult = 60  # .sleep works with seconds, to get minutes multiply by 60
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not tech support. If you are having a problem *running* code that *someone else has written*, please consult the documentation for that program, or contact the author (for example by using an issue tracker for the project). Stack Overflow is generally for questions about code that *you* either *have written or are actively trying to write*.

Answer (score 0):

You are using PyYAML's old `load()` function which for the longest time defaulted to possible unsafe behavior on unchecked YAML. That is why in 2020
this default was finally [deprecated](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/wiki/PyYAML-yaml.load(input)-Deprecation).

If you don't have any tags in your YAML you should use:

```
document = yaml.safe_load(document)
```

if you do have tags in your YAML you can use

```
`yaml.load(document, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)`
```

, but note that would require registering of classes for the tags. Few (too few) programs use tags, so try the `safe_load` option first to see if that works.

Please note that the [recommended extension](https://yaml.org/faq.html) for YAML files has been `.yaml` since 2006.